# PHP difficulty, $_POST only posting first word in input value

Tags: php, forms, post

So I have this problem where if I do this.

```
<input type="text" name="adres" value='.$adres.'>
```

it only shows the first word of the submitted value.

(Please note that this is like a confirmation check
the actual data is already sent on a different form)

altho, if I do echo `$adres`; (I am echoing it out of the form, just to check if $_POST had the right value with it) it will just show it all, while if I do this in the input value it will only show the first word
I really don't know why it does that, and can't seem to find a fix for it.

```
<?php 

$postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
$email = $_POST['email'];   
$naam = $_POST['naam'];     
$commentaar = $_POST['comment'];    
$plaats = $_POST['woonplaats']; 
$adres = $_POST['adres'];

echo '<h3>Factuur Gegevens</h3>
            <section>
                <label class="label">Naam: </label>
                    <label class="input">
                    <i class="icon-append fa-user"></i>
                    <input type="text" name="naam" value='.$naam.'>
                </label>
            </section>

            <section>
                <label class="label">Adres: </label>
                    <label class="input">
                    <i class="icon-append fa-home"></i>
                    <input type="text" name="adres" value='.$adres.'>
                </label>
            </section>              
            <div class="row">
                <section class="col col-8">
                    <label class="label">Woonplaats: </label>
                        <label class="input">
                        <input type="text" name="woonplaats" value='.$plaats.'>
                    </label>
                </section>

                <section class="col col-4">
                    <label class="label">Postcode: </label>
                        <label class="input">
                        <input type="text" name="postcode" value='.$postcode.'>
                    </label>
                </section>
            </div>

            <section>
                <label class="label">Email: </label>
                <label class="input">
                    <i class="icon-append fa-envelope"></i>
                    <input type="text" name="email" value='.$email.'>
            </label>
            </section>

            <section>
                <label class="label">Comment</label>
                <label class="textarea">
                    <i class="icon-append fa-comments"></i>
                    <textarea rows="4" name="comment" >'. $commentaar .'</textarea>
                </label>
            </section>';

function emailcheck(){ 
    global $email;
    if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo "Yay valid email <br>";
    }
    else {
        echo " booh, wrong email :c";
    }
 }

 function postcodecheck() {
    global $postcode;
    if(preg_match('/^[1-9]{1}[0-9]{3}[[:space:]]?[a-z]{2}$/i', $postcode)) {
        echo "<br> Yay, valid postcode ( $postcode )";
    }
    else {
        echo "Booh, wrong postcode :c";
    }
 }
```

?>

The outcome looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqpoR.png

Can someone help me out here?
Jordy

Comment: Do you have `register_globals` enabled? Can you show your full PHP code? What do you see when you `print_r($_POST);`?

Comment: please post the code indetail..

Comment: Added the script that inserts the data in the input values.

Comment: add double quotes around text box value

Comment: @user3122479: How does your HTML look like after generation? (Without the PHP code, actual content)

Comment: Like this guys http://i.imgur.com/mvl2jLq.png

Comment: please echo or print_r $adres. need to know what you are getting in that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing the address is multi-line and you are trying to stick it in an input box, so only the first line of the address is showing. Try a `<textarea></textarea>` instead.

Comment: Ahh that explains why, so an input value can not have multi-line, cheers! This one worked!

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the quotes around value:

```
<input type="text" name="adres" value="'.$adres.'">
```

Comment: It is not that, it actually works, it display as it's supposed to, but apparantly textboxes are not allowed to have multi-line texting in their value.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
 <input type="text" name="adres" value="'.$adres.'">
```

Instead of

```
 <input type="text" name="adres" value='.$adres.'>
```